# Run js function only if CSS class is available

Tags: javascript, css

The problem is that the following function:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  // Check the viewport status
  if (inViewport(project1)) {
    pagination1.style.background = "#e3e3e3";
  } else {
    pagination1.style.background = "transparent";
  }
});
```

gives an error every time I scroll on the page that doesn't have a DIV with the class 'project1' on it.

Is there a way to trigger this function only when that DIV/class is set. Actually I'd like that the DIV itself triggers the function.

Full code taking into account the answers below, but **doesn't work yet**:

```
"use strict";

function inViewport(element) {
  // Get the elements position relative to the viewport
  var bb = element.getBoundingClientRect(); // Check if the element is outside the viewport
  // Then invert the returned value because you want to know the opposite

  return !(bb.top > innerHeight || bb.bottom < 0);
}

var hfirst1 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-first1");
var hfirst2 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-first2");
var hfirst3 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-first3");
var hfirst4 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-first4");
var hfirst5 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-first5");
var hfirst6 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-first6");

var hsecond1 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-second1");
var hsecond2 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-second2");
var hsecond3 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-second3");
var hsecond4 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-second4");
var hsecond5 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-second5");
var hsecond6 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-second6");

var hthird1 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-third1");
var hthird2 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-third2");
var hthird3 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-third3");
var hthird4 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-third4");
var hthird5 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-third5");
var hthird6 = document.querySelector(".hashtag-third6");

var n1 = document.querySelector(".name1");
var n2 = document.querySelector(".name2");
var n3 = document.querySelector(".name3");
var n4 = document.querySelector(".name4");
var n5 = document.querySelector(".name5");
var n6 = document.querySelector(".name6");

var d1 = document.querySelector(".details1");
var d2 = document.querySelector(".details2");
var d3 = document.querySelector(".details3");
var d4 = document.querySelector(".details4");
var d5 = document.querySelector(".details5");
var d6 = document.querySelector(".details6");

var project1 = document.querySelector(".project-trigger1");
var project2 = document.querySelector(".project-trigger2");
var project3 = document.querySelector(".project-trigger3");
var project4 = document.querySelector(".project-trigger4");
var project5 = document.querySelector(".project-trigger5");
var project6 = document.querySelector(".project-trigger6");

var pagination1 = document.querySelector(".bullet1");
var pagination2 = document.querySelector(".bullet2");
var pagination3 = document.querySelector(".bullet3");
var pagination4 = document.querySelector(".bullet4");
var pagination5 = document.querySelector(".bullet5");
var pagination6 = document.querySelector(".bullet6"); // Listen for the scroll event


document.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  // check if exists
  if(document.getElementsByClassName("project-trigger1").length > 0)
  {
    //then run the function
    pagination1.style.background = inViewport(project1) ? "#e3e3e3" : "transparent";
    hfirst1.style.color = inViewport(project1) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    hsecond1.style.color = inViewport(project1) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    hthird1.style.color = inViewport(project1) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    n1.style.color = inViewport(project1) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    n1.style.color = inViewport(project1) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
  }
});
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  // check if exists
  if(document.getElementsByClassName("project-trigger2").length > 0)
  {
    //then run the function
    pagination2.style.background = inViewport(project2) ? "#e3e3e3" : "transparent";
    hfirst2.style.color = inViewport(project2) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    hsecond2.style.color = inViewport(project2) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    hthird2.style.color = inViewport(project2) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    n2.style.color = inViewport(project2) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    n2.style.color = inViewport(project2) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
  }
});
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  // check if exists
  if(document.getElementsByClassName("project3").length > 0)
  {
    //then run the function
    pagination3.style.background = inViewport(project3) ? "#e3e3e3" : "transparent";
    hfirst3.style.color = inViewport(project3) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    hsecond3.style.color = inViewport(project3) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    hthird3.style.color = inViewport(project3) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    n3.style.color = inViewport(project3) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    n3.style.color = inViewport(project3) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
  }
});
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  // check if exists
  if(document.getElementsByClassName("project-trigger4").length > 0)
  {
    //then run the function
    pagination4.style.background = inViewport(project4) ? "#e3e3e3" : "transparent";
    hfirst4.style.color = inViewport(project4) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    hsecond4.style.color = inViewport(project4) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    hthird4.style.color = inViewport(project4) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    n4.style.color = inViewport(project4) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    n4.style.color = inViewport(project4) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
  }
});
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  // check if exists
  if(document.getElementsByClassName("project-trigger5").length > 0)
  {
    //then run the function
    pagination5.style.background = inViewport(project5) ? "#e3e3e3" : "transparent";
    hfirst5.style.color = inViewport(project5) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    hsecond5.style.color = inViewport(project5) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    hthird5.style.color = inViewport(project5) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    n5.style.color = inViewport(project5) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    n5.style.color = inViewport(project5) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
  }
});
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  // check if exists
  if(document.getElementsByClassName("project-trigger6").length > 0)
  {
    //then run the function
    pagination6.style.background = inViewport(project6) ? "#e3e3e3" : "transparent";
    hfirst6.style.color = inViewport(project6) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    hsecond6.style.color = inViewport(project6) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    hthird6.style.color = inViewport(project6) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    n6.style.color = inViewport(project6) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
    n6.style.color = inViewport(project6) ? "#ffffff" : "transparent";
  }
});
```

**Project is a portfolio site with up to 20+ projects (vertical displayed > all projects on top of each other) . Each project is a slider containing images of art projects. Project description, title and number should be displayed in the navigationbar on the top (position: fixed) only when the respective project scrolls into view.**

The js script should be set up for 30+ projects which are added by cms gradually. This means that at the beginning some projects are set up in the js script but not yet added by cms.

Comment: You have a js variable `project1` but its not defined anywhere in the code you show. Where is it defined & what is it?

Comment: Can you show the code where you define the `project1` variable?

Comment: thanks for your requests. updated by initial post with full code taking into account the answer from estavillo

Comment: Project description added.

Comment: You've got *way* too much repetition in that code. What does your HTML look like? If all the elements of a single project are descendants of a common ancestor, this can be significantly shortened.

Comment: The html is fully driven by cms. For example the  <section id="project#" class="project#">: project number # comes from the cms item number of each project. Same regarding the project details. I.e the cms items itself set the right classes to each div. Hope this helps. if you have any ideas for shortening the code your very welcome ;-)

Comment: Are `.name1`, `.details1`, `.bullet1`, etc., all inside `section#project1`?

Comment: no, they are in a separate section with position fixed top/left. The projects itself are in a fullscreen section with position relative (one project over each other)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could try checking if the div exists first.

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  // check if exists
  if(document.getElementsByClassName('project1').length > 0)
  {
     //then avoid redundancy/the if statement with a ternary
     pagination1.style.background = inViewport(project1) ? "#e3e3e3" : "transparent";
  }
});
```

hope this helps

Comment: you forgot you already have `project1`. No need to query the entire DOM on a heavy event like *scroll* - trying to find class elements. So that's unhelpful - in the current state. `if (project1 && project1.length)` is quite enough. But than there's the possibly unhandled `pagination1`....

Comment: thanks for helping out. Unfortunately the code doesn't work yet. I've updated by post and posted the full code below. your all help is very welcome!

Comment: Project description added.

Comment: have it soved. the code below from estavillo does the trick. ```if(document.getElementsByClassName('project1').length > 0)``` needs a the class of the trigger, not the var I've set for the class. Thanks estavillo! I have updated the code in my question above by class name and it works right for me.